# Is it possible to use ExoPlayer only for downloading an HLS stream but my own code for displaying it?

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I need to write some code to download an m3u8 stream but I need to be able to manipulate the stream after it has been downloaded and I need to be able to display it with my own code. Is it possible to do that with ExoPlayer? Essentially I just want ExoPlayer to handle all the download parts.

Thanks.

Comment: did you successfully download video using exoplayer?

Comment: No, never did. I use their m3u8 classes but not their networking code.

Comment: can you tell me how you download classes?

Comment: You mean their code? I don't use their source code directly, just use their gradle component under dependencies.